# Get raw audio data at a standard playback rate

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-audio

I'd like to receive audio data (binary) as an audio file is playing back. I know I can get the whole blob of data using `NSFileManager`, but I need to be able to receive the data live as the audio file is playing.

I was looking into Core Audio, specifically the [Extended Audio File API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007912). Anyone know how to go about extracting data using this method? Or if there is another way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking in to the [AVFoundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html), in particular the [`AVAssetReader`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetReader_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009515) and [`AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetReaderTrackOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009691) classes for getting access to the samples contained in an audio track. The [`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530) and [`AVPlayerItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVPlayerItem) classes should expose sufficient about the playback time position via properties and notifications to allow you to match up audio samples with the playing audio.